# Bulk upsert best practices for PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, multithreading, amazon-web-services, jdbc

I have a source table (staging table) with million records and a target table (application table) with million records in PostgreSQL. The target table is being used by a mobile application (synchronous).

I have to do merge (insert on conflict) from source table to target table and also delete some records in target table conditionally. This has to happen once in every 4 hours (because data in stage table is from a different source system). I shouldn't use Stored Procedures because of some code maintenance reasons.

1. Can I use JDBC to execute multiple queries in
   parallel with different offset and limit? Will it improve performance?

   **insert into test ...
   select ... from test_stg
   order by .. OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1000 ROW ONLY
   on conflict (constraint...)
   do update
   set ...**
2. What is the best way of running the queries parallelly within a single transaction (atomic) from Java code?

Note: I can perform delete operation in target table, once if I succeed on merge from stage to actual table.

Answer (score 1):

I would DELETE and INSERT/UPDATE in one Go, something like this:

```
WITH cte_delete AS (
    DELETE FROM test_stg
    RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO test
SELECT *
FROM    cte_delete
ON CONFLICT (...)
DO UPDATE ...;
```

I wouldn't start with any other performance optimisations. Keeping things simple and straight forward, works best most of the time. And you can't fix any problem if you don't have a problem.